# Save DateTime.Now between switching cultures

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, .net-4.0, localization

I have an asp.net mvc application. It's multilanguages and writes some values in cookie. The problem occurs if the currentCulture (language) of application and the value of DateTime stored in cookie has different formats. Therefore I've decided to store and retrieve DateTime values only in English culture. But I've faced with the trouble.

```
 var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; //for example, ru-RU
 var currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

 var englishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = englishCulture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = englishCulture;

 var dateTime = DateTime.Now;  //  10/22/2011 9:56:15 AM (in English)


 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUICulture;

 return dateTime;              //   22.10.2011 9:56:15 (in Russian). But why?
```

I want to return DateTime.Now in English culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime` does not store culture information. It's when you call `ToString` that the culture matters. If you want to format it with a specific culture before returning it, you need to return it as a string.

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString(cultureInfo);
```

Probably though you should return it as a `DateTime` (and you probably want to use [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) so that it works across timezones) and format it using the invariant culture: [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).

Comment: Why does the value of the local variable "dateTime" has been changed?

Comment: Err.. what? It *hasn't* changed - it is just formatted differently. Do you mean "why does the string representation of the date change?" It's because when your debugger calls ToString that method uses the current culture and you changed that.

Comment: Is it possible to return DateTime struct (not string) in en-US culture, if the current culture isn't en-US?

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: A DateTime doesn't store the culture. The culture is only relevant when you format it to string. What are you trying to achieve? Why not use the InvariantCulture? This will work the same for everyone.

Comment: Please reread Mark's answer: DateTime does not hold culture information. Period. But it can hold time zone information. Which is not culture. Most countries belong to 1 timezone but some, including US, span accross several timezones. That's why Mark suggest using DateTime.UtcNow as this is user location independant.